# Order of data items returned by jquery is different in Firefox to MS browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

We have a convention where we need to read the first data item in an elements set of data items, but we're finding that firefox sorts the data items so you can't rely on the first item being returned.

```js
var x = $("#x").data();

var y = "";
for (k in x) {
 y += k + "=" + x[k] + ", ";
}
$("#x").text(y);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="x" data-xfirst="1" data-asecond="2">

</div>
```

If you run this in Edge or IE, you "correctly" get xfirst first. If you run it in firefox, you get asecond first.

Edit: just tried in Chrome and that behaves the same as FF

How can I address these data attributes in the order they were placed in the DOM ?

thanks

Comment: Interestingly, when I use the browsers "dataset" property (instead of Jquery data()), the data items are reversed. So IE and Edge now shows asecond first, xfirst second, and FF shows xfirst first, asecond second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data()` method returns an object which is just a collection of key-value pairs - how they get stored and iterated over is not guaranteed to be in any order like an indexed array and will be different across browsers/JS engines. IE/Edge getting it right for your particular case is just chance.

I think what you need to do is analyze the string of the element using `outerHTML`. I believe this string will contain data attributes as they appear in the DOM (please test across browsers). Then you just need to find the first occurrence of a `data-` attribute. This is pretty straightforward using string's `indexOf()` method (or you could use a regular expression):

```js
const elemStr = document.getElementById('x').outerHTML;
const dataIndex = elemStr.indexOf('data-');

let quoteIndexes = [-1, -1];

// This is the first occurance of a data attribute
if (dataIndex > -1) {

  // Find the opening and end quote indexes of the data attribute value
  quoteIndexes[0] = elemStr.indexOf('"', dataIndex);
  quoteIndexes[1] = elemStr.indexOf('"', quoteIndexes[0]+1);
  
  if (quoteIndexes[0] > -1 && quoteIndexes[1] > -1) {
    console.log(`First data attribute: ${elemStr.substring(dataIndex, quoteIndexes[1]+1)}`);
    console.log(`Key: ${elemStr.substring(dataIndex+5, quoteIndexes[0]-1)}`);
    console.log(`Value: ${elemStr.substring(quoteIndexes[0]+1, quoteIndexes[1])}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="x" style="width:100px;" data-name="test" data-class="foo" data-type="bar" class="some classes"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you did a good job on putting that together, although its quite a nasty thing to put in your code. Still I'll take this if nothing better comes along. I did take a look at the attributes collection of the element and even that is reversed in FF compared to ie/edge

Comment: I'll accept this answer although its not how I fixed it in the end. I decided instead that relying on the order of attributes was a daft idea and went with a better model. It took a lot of coding but its a more elegant solution than parsing outerHTML :--)